# seek in svg animation timeline

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an animation in svg. I would like to seek the animation. for example,I have  a seek bar(can change positions using mouse click) and I have an animation in svg where the duration is 5 seconds.  Depending on the position of seek-bar, animation also changes.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [setCurrentTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__setCurrentTime) will adjust the animation timeline, just make your seek bar call that on the `<svg>` root element whenever it is adjusted.

Comment: It seems that setCurrentTime doesn't work properly in Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=166164 I haven't tested, but it seems like this likely affects other WebKit-based browsers too: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105301